# How do I calculate this limit of factorial?

Tags: factorial

I am having trouble solving this problem. If anyone could help me, I would be so thankful.

[image: picture of the problem]

Comment: What course is this problem for? Do you need to give a delta epsilon proof or is it high school where you can get away with "if $n$ gets very big, then $n!$ gets much bigger than $n^4$?

Comment: Anyway a question not showing any effort (not even typing the formula) doesn't need to be answered.

Comment: @WhatsUp - newbies rarely have the LaTeX skills to post a readable formula. It is understandable that they would resort to a picture (which they must also post as a link, as they are not allowed to embed them until they have more rep). It is true that they should have shown their own efforts, but please restrain your criticisms to things that they could have realistically done better.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That's why I put the "not even" part in parentheses, as it's a secondary issue.

Comment: @WhatsUp - If you considered it "secondary", then you should have detailed your primary issue instead of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day,
to me there's a simple and informal way to solve this problem, and please correct me if I go wrong.

We could factor n!, at least ideally, being n! the fastest function of n growing to infinity here. We can therefore ignore n^3 and n^4 and simply consider the ratio between the coefficients of this two fastest (and equal) functions:
-2/3. That's the solution.

If you asked for a more detailed and rigorous solutions, and this is not for high school, then others on this site, more trustworthy than me, will give for sure an exact explanation on how to solve the question.

Hope to help, even a little

Bye! :)